# Host ASP.Net C# website to Apache or weblogic

Tags: asp.net, apache, iis, weblogic

We have a Asp.Net website code behind C# framework 4.0 hosted on IIS 6.2. Now we have been asked to migrate it to either Apache or weblogic server.
My question is where can we host our website where minimal changes are needed to host our website. And based on your experience do we need to do any code changes in our web site to make it compatible with Apache or Web logic server. 
Kindly suggest where should we migrate so that minimal or no code changes needed. and minimal efforts for hosting.

Comment: Using Apache means migrating your application code to PHP.
Using WebLogic Server means migrating your application code to Java/J2ee
Directly hosting your .Net application under apache or weblogic is not possible without rewriting your application, i'm afraid.

Comment: This is possible using mod_aspdotnet on apache and for weblogic - http://weblogic.sys-con.com/node/138266

Comment: mod_aspdotnet has been retired from the ASF and is no longer supported. The SourceForge project has no activity for at least 3 years. Good luck.
WeBlogic does not understand .Net and C#

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC can be hosted only on IIS. you must create ASP.NET core (multiplatform ASP.NET framework) application that you can be deployed on apatche or nginx.

https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x